# How do pencil erasers erase on a fundamental level?

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

One could say we're taking advantage of friction, but I want to dig deeper down to molecular/atomic level: what's the process or chain that happens when one erases from a macroscopic to a more fundamental level?